# getImageData not picking up RGB values for image with data-src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipulate a class based on the colour of an image using getImageData. I'm using the code below which is getting the image but it's returning 0,0,0 for the RGB values. It was originally working when the img tag was using a src attribute but since I have changed it to be data-src for lazyload purposes it's now returning R:0 G:0 B:0 A:0

Can anyone help please?

```
var img = document.getElementById('hero-image');

  console.log(img);

    if(img !== null) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    console.log(canvas.width);

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

              console.log(canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height));

    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(1, 1, 1, 1).data;

              console.log(pixelData);

    console.log('R: ' + pixelData[0] + '<br>G: ' + pixelData[1] + '<br>B: ' + pixelData[2] + '<br>A: ' + pixelData[3]);

    var avg = (pixelData[0] + pixelData[1] + pixelData[2]) / 3;

    if (avg < 100) {
        console.log('dark');
        $('.main-nav').removeClass('navbar-light');
      }
    else {
        console.log('light');
        $('.main-nav').removeClass('navbar-dark');
        $('.main-nav').addClass('navbar-light');
    }
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});

function init() {
  ImageSliders();
  initContactForm();
  typedBanners();
  scrollingAnimations();
  navBarHide();
  animateOnLoadPosition();
  lazyLoadImages();
  navbarColour();
  openSubscribePanel();
};
```

Comment: Could you add the img HTML as well just to see? Why would this work with `data-src`? If you are lazyloading, how do you know the image is there?

Comment: Isn't this because you try to use the pixel data before the whole image is actually loaded?

Comment: @Cyclonecode I'm loading the function after the lazyload function so i don't think so? I've updated my code to show how it's ordered

Comment: try to call the function inside $(window).load() event

Comment: @mbadeveloper thanks mate that's worked!

Comment: @Shaun can you please mark is as valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the function inside $(window).load() event